# Is there a reason to apply BPM to agile methodologies such as SCRUM?

Tags: agile, process-improvement

Is there a good reason to apply **BPM** to **agile methodologies** such as SCRUM in order to improve the Agile process?

Comment: Agile isn't a methodology, nor even a group of methodologies. It's a philosophy and set of principals. To assume that "Agile is a mature methodology" has a false premise. Any one striving for agility will constantly reflect and adjust their process... *forever*. A particular Agile team may have a mature process, but I think you're thinking of Agile wrong. Have you read the manifesto? It's not as daunting as people think. It and the 12 principals fit onto a poster. I recommend giving it a read.

Comment: I edited the question. _Mature_ is not the word I was looking for, maybe _solid_ would be a better word.  And I know that teams should improve the process day after day, but this is not the point of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agile methodologies already have a self-improvement process built in. So applying BPM to any agile method itself is superfluous.

However, you may want to apply BPM to the whole company, to see if your agile method actually is the optimal approach to your companies goal.